# format code without spaces ( remove tabulator space from code )

Tags: netbeans, format

I have formated code in netbeans:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Question:

How to **remove tabulator spaces** from code (any JS, PHP, CSS) **to get** this **output** in IDE?

*(possibly in **NetBeans**, but it can be any program.)*

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="">Menu</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">Menu</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of tools for that over the internet.

Try this one: http://www.odditysoftware.com/page-webtools16.htm

It has some HTML specific settings and more.